# Im having trouble understanding how to pass an array to a method, and return an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am having trouble finishing this intro to Java assignment. My goal is pass nums[] into the method array() and then have array() return an ArrayList containing all of the "freezing" temps found in nums[]. Any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program73 {

    public static int[] array(int[] array) {

        return array;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nums[] = new int[14];

        System.out.println("The temperatures in the last two weeks...: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

            nums[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 11) + 50;

            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println("These 5 were below freezing...:");

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to return a `List`, you need to change the return type of `array()` to do that.  Then in your method, create a new `ArrayList`, and copy all the data from the input array into it, and return it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I am struggling with understanding how I even create ArrayLists or pass arrays into methods. Every time I try im always throwing errors so I get stuck at that point

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` or more generally a `List` is nothing more than a class that implements the `List interface` to facilitate manipulating collections of data.

In the case of `ArrayList` it uses a regular array (e.g. Object[]) to store the data while providing various methods to navigate and manipulate the list. Some specific differences from the **users point of view** between an `ArrayList` and an `array` are.

- ArrayLists grow dynamically and do not need to be pre-allocated.
- You can delete (remove) an element anywhere from an ArrayList.
- You can see if the ArrayList contains a specific element.
- You can easily sort an ArrayList
- many other examples also exist.

None of the above capabilities are free.  They are simply methods implemented in a class, acting as a front-end to an array to make writing code easier.

```
int [] array = new int[10];
// fill the array with ints

List<Integer> list = toList(array);


public List<Integer> toList(int[] a) {
  // do something with a
  // like print them out.
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i : a) {
     list.add(i);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: So the method(int[] a) is void and not a value returning method. Is there a special type I need to set it to? or should it be int?

Comment: @Brandon  Sorry about that.  I made a grave error (like not paying attention).

Comment: I have never used List before, and my book is not showing me anything like list. This is honestly so confusing and im very frustrated right now

Comment: `List` is just the name of the interface that `ArrayList` implements.  In the above example, you can also put `ArrayList<Integer>` everywhere I put `List<Integer>`  and it will work.

Comment: I found this article on JavaWorld.  It explains interfaces pretty well using some examples with `ArrayList`  [Interfaces in Java](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3171300/java-101-interfaces-in-java.html)